# Защита загруженных изображений документов в Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет!

Клиента на сайте загружают изображениия своих документов. Как обезопасить такие изображения от кражи? В теории, злоумышленник может просканировать папки сайта и найти все загруженные в папку изображения.

Comment: Например, через htaccess. Или хранить изображения в SQL через BLOB, со всеми вытекающим нюансами.

Comment: На подбор и проверку только всех восьмибуквенных латинских комбинаций у него уйдет шесть лет, если считать, что средняя скорость проверки при этом - 1 мс на комбинацию, и что я не налажал при расчетах, так что насчет "просканировать папки сайта" - это вряд ли (а вот выйти на документы по косвенным данным - это да)

Comment: В теории можно воспользоваться программой телепорт и скопировать все директории сайта, включая папку с изображениям. Этого можно избежать?

Answer (score 1):

Все, что открывается в браузере - может быть скопировано.. Ответ: никак.. накладывайте watermark и т.д...
От копирования - никак не защититесь..